# How to retrieve last MySQL INSERT ID from db_merge()

Tags: 7, database

I am using db_merge for inserting or updating new records in my table.
I want to get the last inserted record id from this table, Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps having a timestamp column will make it easier to get last updated/inserted record. `SELECT foo FROM bar ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0,1`

Comment: No Need to add additional column.

Answer (score 7):

While there is [RETURN_INSERT_ID](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/constant/Database%3a%3aRETURN_INSERT_ID/7) which can be used with [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7), I could not find a way to use with [db_merge()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_merge/7).

```
<?php
  $query = "INSERT INTO {table_name} (col1, col2) VALUES (:arg1, :arg2)";
  $args = array(':arg1' => $val1, ':arg2' => $val2);
  $last_id = db_query($query, $args, array('return' => Database::RETURN_INSERT_ID));
?
```

I think you will have to retrieve the last ID with another query, but you would need to check with [MergeQuery::STATUS_INSERT](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/constant/MergeQuery%3a%3aSTATUS_INSERT/7).

```
$status = db_merge('example')
  ->key(array('name' => $name))
  ->fields(array(
      'field1' => $value1,
      'field2' => $value2,
  ))
  ->execute()

if( $status == MergeQuery::STATUS_INSERT ) {
      $last_id = db_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")->fetchField();
}
```

Comment: @Ravindra I don't understand why you can't just use this one? You already know whether or not you're performing an Insert/Update based on the contents of `$keyvalue`, so just add a simple `else { $last_id = $keyvalue; }` to the above code and you're done :)

Comment: hey i tried this but not working..

Comment: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` is MySQL only, pretty much the same result as `SELECT MAX(id)` where id is the auto_increment/serial field

Comment: @DavidThomas If I remember rightly `LAST_INSERT_ID` is thread safe while `MAX` isn't (necessarily). I might be wrong though I would have read that some years ago now

Comment: @Ravindra Have you come across [`drupal_write_record()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7)? If you don't need the advanced functionality provided by `db_merge()` (conditional updates, etc) then you can just use that and save yourself the headache

Comment: @Clive you're right, but calling `LAST_INSERT_ID()` vs `MAX(id)` in the same function, directly after db_merge should give the same result afaik which I think is what OP is wanting to do there... Maybe some chance of race condition on the select from separate insert process, so perhaps last_insert_id() is ok there if mysql.

Comment: @DavidThomas I think so long as it's in a transaction that's true, outside of a transaction I'm not sure if there's a potential race condition there. But I'm not bothered enough to check ;)

Comment: @RavindraSingh, check how `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is used with db_select() at [the other question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59000/last-insert-id-with-selectquery).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the last inserted record id from this table...

You could do a second query, to get the latest inserted id:

```
$max_id = db_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM {table}")->fetchField();
```

That will return the latest inserted id, but not the id of the latest updated.

Comment: David in case of db_merge() it is not mandatory that the Max id in the table is new record it may be older and updated on that time only.

Comment: Just check the returned value from db_merge, if it was an insert you MUST query for the highest id value, if it was an update then no ID should be returned.

Comment: if id does not insert any new records that time it fails.

Comment: If an existing record was updated this would give incorrect result right ?

Comment: If you have DESC LIMIT 1 in your query, no need MAX().

Comment: @Sithu, yeah, it's a bit of overkill ;)

Comment: No last insert id for an update, perhaps I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hey in Drupal 6  we can use

```
db_last_insert_id('table_name', 'name');
```

This gives the last inserted id.

Comment: [db_last_insert_id() is not in D7 anymore](http://drupal.org/node/729970).

Answer (score -1):

You can use this.

```
      $node = db_select('table_name', 'f')
      ->fields('f', array('field_you_want'))
      ->condition('field', 'condition', 'expression')
      ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
      ->range(0,1);
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Suppose i need to get last inserted id so please give me an example.

Comment: We are already getting the last inserted by using the orderBy() method, If you send DESC and limit results to 1

Comment: If it does not insert new record that time it only updates the values and may be last (Max) id of row will not affect